# How to use the device token in method other than didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I got the device token through `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method. I wanted to use the device token in another method. I tried it in this way,

In `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method:

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
// str is the NSString which is declared in the appDelegate.h file as global variable
```

In `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method:

```
 NSLog(@"Device Token : %@",str);
```

When i do like this the `Device Token` is returning as "nosniff".

How can i store this device token in a global variable and use it in the other class or in other method.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the device token to the `NSUserDefaults` dictionary like so:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

This can then be accessed in other methods like so:

```
NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your app delegate class define method `+ (CustomAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate` whose implementation should look like this one:

```
+ (CustomAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
     return (CustomAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

where `CustomAppDelegate` is name of your app delegate class.

In method your need to get value of `str` variable you should type following:

```
NSString *token = [[CustomAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] str];
```

where `CustomAppDelegate` is name of your app delegate class and `str` is synthesized property (or name of the method) where device token is stored.

Before calling `sharedAppDelegate` don't forget to `import "CustomAppDelegate.h"`

Comment: This is opening the app launch screen but then all blank the view controllers are not loading , is there any alternate example you can give as I have tried this but --> App launch --> DidfinishlaunchwithOption Called --> Initial View controller not called for viewdidload if i put this [[UIapplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:self] in did finish launch